# Initialization of non-trivial thread_local variables: why on demand only?

Tags: c++11, elf, thread-local-storage

thread_local data is value initialized by C++ runtime using the data from `.tdata`/`.tbss` sections (assuming ELF abi). It appears feasible, therefore, to add another pair of sections, called `.tinit`/`.tfini`. Those section could contain code which will always run when subordinate threads are started and terminated and after thread local memory was established (analogously to `.init`/`.fini` sections which are executed at main thread start/end). The constructors and destructors for non-trivial thread local objects could then be lumped by linker into those.

The functionality of supposed `.tfini` section is presently handled by dynamic machinery of `__cxa_thread_atexit` and friends (at sizable overhead). However, no dedicated instrumentation for "automagic" thread initialization code is provided by the runtime: for all non-trivial thread local objects compiler must emit guard variables which are checked on each access.

So the question is: was the approach outlined above evaluated by the thread local data feature architects? What drawbacks were identified (apart from changes to semantics of thread execution which are clearly not set in stone)?

Comment: Just curious, was the answer helpful?

Comment: No, it was not.

Comment: I suggest you ask clarifying questions then.

Answer (score 0):

So as you pointed out, ELF thread local variables (i.e. marked with `__thread`) have to be initialized with constant expressions. This is due to some design decision about implementation.

**Insight 1**: most threads will not access all thread-local data that's available in application. Imagine some computation library which starts several threads to speed up execution - these threads most likely access this library's internal thread-locals, not thread-locals from other libs. That's why Glibc allocates thread-local storage *on demand* i.e. when app. code first accesses it via `__tls_get_addr` (*some* TLS blocks will be allocated at startup but that's more an optimization than requirement).

**Insight 2**: allowing arbitrary constructors to work during TLS allocation (i.e. inside `__tls_get_addr`) would be a *huge* source of deadlocks races as `__tls_get_addr` may be called at arbitrary point in code (whenever the first reference to TLS variable is made).

I believe this is what led designers to prohibiting dynamic initialization of TLS variables alltogether.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "prohibiting dynamic initialization alltogether"? Dynamic thread initialization sections were discussed by the C++ committee some years ago; I am interested to see the link to the outcome of those discussion. Also, your "insight 1" is mostly incorrect when real world apps are concerned (consider logging and metrics libraries, random state/crypto providers and fancy concurrent data structures).

Comment: @oakad Actually I thought we are only discussing GCC TLS. Constant initializers requirement is mentioned in [their docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Thread-Local.html). Note that GNU TLS pre-dates C++ TLS by ~7 years.